# Change into a theme Top link (login my wishlist check out My account). But My cart creates separate link.

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, theme, shopping-cart, position

I just use Magento top.links function. but it will display all link Like Myaccont,My wishlist,Mycart,checkout,login. but  i want create sepate link OF **mycart** i can display anywhere in my header. Can you Please tell me what type of step i can do create sepate link of **[image: MYcart]**

I want to create this type of. i want to create separate  cart Link?
Please Help me?

Comment: are you want to spearete cart link using top link

Comment: Yes i will found solution [This Link](http://czbok.wordpress.com/2013/12/15/get-total-items-and-total-price-in-shopping-cart-in-magento/).

Comment: ok,you did not want cart link using toplink..then it is wk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Will Found Solution of the question 
`$count = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();  //get total items in cart
  $total = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(); //get total price
  if($count==0)
  {
    echo $this->__('<a href="'.$cart_url.'" >(0 ITEMS)</a>',$count);
  }
  if($count==1)
  {
    echo $this->__('<a href="'.$cart_url.'" >(1 ITEM)</a>',$count);
  }
  if($count>1)
  {
    echo $this->__('<a href="'.$cart_url.'" >(%s ITMES)</a>',$count);
  }
  echo $this->__('<a href="'.$cart_url.'" >Total: %s', $this->helper('core')->formatPrice($total, false));`